# How to display chrome extension in above menubar ?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created Google chrome extension. but that can,t be display on upper in menu bar . Below code work perfect but just i want display my extention icon on
above beside of url tag. Help me if any one know ?
I want to launch than every time i have to go in chrome://extensions/

[image]

**manifest.json**

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "version": "2.1",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon_16.png",
      "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "app": {
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"]
      }
    }
}
```

**MAIN.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
// Center window on screen.
var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
var width = 500;
var height = 300;

chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
  id: "helloWorldID",
  outerBounds: {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
    top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
  }
});
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
   <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, you haven't created an [*extension*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions).

What you have created is an [*app*](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), as indicated by the `"app"` key in your manifest. Apps cannot integrate with the browser this way, so you need to make an extension.

You need to throw away your code and follow the extension guides to make one: [Getting Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) and [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Specifically, the UI element you're asking about is called a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

Comment: Yup Got it now Thanks